ML-Classification of Motor Imagery EEG data only at 50% in MatLab
I'm trying to do ML-classification on some Motor Imagery EEG data and for a long time now I've been stuck at ~50% being correctly classified. This is my first time working with EEG data and signal-processing. This is also my first question on StackExchange so I'm sorry for the long post. You don't have to read all the code but if you could nudge me in the right direction, I would be very happy.
I don't know whether I don't understand the datafiles correctly, if i don't filter correctly or if my feature extraction is wrong. Either way, everything I've tried gives around 50% correct classification every single time. The ICA and CSP in  the code below have been my last two attempts to solve the problem.
Data description
I use the "2. Two class motor imagery (002-2014)" from https://bnci-horizon-2020.eu/database/data-sets. There are two classes, "righthand" and "feet". The dataset is as follows:

14 participants
1 session of 8 runs per participant (5 for training and 3 for testing)
20 trials in one run (10 trials for righthand and 10 for feet)
15 electrode channels
512 sampling rate

The datafiles on the website is ".mat" files such that e.g. "S01T.mat" contains 5 structs, one for each training run, and each struct contains "X", "trial", "y", "fs" and "classes". Here "X" is the Nx15 data matrix, "trial" is the 1x20 vector of trial starting points (i think), "y" denotes 1x20 vector of classes corresponding to each trial (either 1 or 2), "fs" is just the sampling rate 512 and "classes" is a 1x2 vector specifying that 1 is righthand and 2 is feet. According to the description on the website https://lampx.tugraz.at/~bci/database/002-2014/description.pdf each trial lasted 5 seconds (under 2. Methods - Summary of the on-line studies set-up).
My pipeline is as follows: Extract Data -> Filter Data -> Extract Features -> Fit Model.
Filtering
I filter the data in the following way:

I filter the data to the frequencies [2, 60] with a high- and lowpass filter and also a notch filter at 50Hz.
I apply ICA to remove artifacts. I remove any components with either a kurtosis or spectral power more than 3 standard deviations away from the mean.
I segment the signal into the individual trials including a pre- and postrial period.
I then use the pretrial period of each trial as baseline to normalize that trial.

In the end I have a 1400x1 struct. Each entry in the struct correspond to one trial and contains a 15x3784 matrix where 15 is the number of electrodes and 3784 is the pretrial+trial+postrial epoch.
Feature Extraction

I calculate a set of CSP-filters using the training data.
I split the CSP-filtered data into 19 frequency-subbands from [4-6] to [54-60]
For each subband i calculate the relative bandpower compared to the mean baseline period of all trials.

Fit Model
I just use MatLabs fitcauto function to automatically fit an ML-model to the features.
Code
For completeness, here is all my code. Sorry that this question is so long. First is the code that extracts the data.
'''
% This is a pre-script used to extracted all the data in the .mat files of
% each subject and store them in matrices for easy handling later.

% Define constants and load files
training_files            = dir("DataFiles\*T.mat");
test_files                = dir("DataFiles\*E.mat");
nr_of_subjects            = 14;
nr_of_training_runs       = 5;
nr_of_test_runs           = 3;
nr_of_trials              = 20;
nr_of_electrodes          = 15;
rows_per_run              = nr_of_trials * nr_of_electrodes;
rows_per_training_session = nr_of_training_runs * rows_per_run;
rows_per_test_session     = nr_of_test_runs * rows_per_run;
frequency                 = 512;
nyquist                   = frequency / 2;
seconds_per_trial         = 5;
pretrial_length           = 712;
posttrial_length          = 512;
data_points_per_epoch     = frequency * seconds_per_trial + pretrial_length + posttrial_length;

total_nr_of_training_rows = rows_per_training_session * nr_of_subjects;
total_nr_of_test_rows     = rows_per_test_session * nr_of_subjects;

% Extract all training and test data into two structs
for i = nr_of_subjects:-1:1
  baseFileNameTrain     = training_files(i).name;
  baseFileNameTest      = test_files(i).name;

  fullFileNameTrain     = fullfile("DataFiles/", baseFileNameTrain);
  fullFileNameTest      = fullfile("DataFiles/", baseFileNameTest);

  training_filedata(i)  = load(fullFileNameTrain);
  test_filedata(i)      = load(fullFileNameTest);
end

% Pre-allocate matrices
ftraind = zeros(total_nr_of_training_rows, data_points_per_epoch);
ftrainc = zeros(total_nr_of_training_rows, 1);
ftestd  = zeros(total_nr_of_test_rows, data_points_per_epoch);
ftestc  = zeros(total_nr_of_test_rows, 1);

% Extract and filter trial data for each subject
for i = 1:nr_of_subjects
    sessionTrain = training_filedata(i).data;
    sessionTest  = test_filedata(i).data;
    
    % Extract and filter training data
    for j = 1:nr_of_training_runs
        % Extract data for the specific run
        run                   = sessionTrain{j};
        data                  = run.X;
        trial_starting_points = run.trial;
        trial_classes         = run.y;

        % Set index
        index = (i-1)*rows_per_training_session + (j-1)*rows_per_run + 1;
        
        % Update the class-vectors with the new classes
        ftrainc(index:(index+rows_per_run-1), 1) = repelem(trial_classes, nr_of_electrodes);

        % Filter and update data
        [filtered_run] = initial_filtering(data, trial_starting_points);

        % Update the data arrays with the filtered data
        ftraind(index:(index+rows_per_run-1), :) = filtered_run;
    end
    
    % Extract test data
    for j = 1:nr_of_test_runs
        % Extract data for specfic run
        run                   = sessionTest{j};
        data                  = run.X;
        trial_starting_points = run.trial;
        trial_classes         = run.y;

        % Set index
        index = (i-1)*rows_per_test_session + (j-1)*rows_per_run + 1;

        % Update the class-vectors with the new data
        ftestc(index:(index+rows_per_run-1), 1) = repelem(trial_classes, nr_of_electrodes);

        % Filter and update data
        [filtered_run] = initial_filtering(data, trial_starting_points);

        % Update the data arrays with the filtered data
        ftestd(index:(index+rows_per_run-1), :) = filtered_run;       
    end
end

writematrix(ftraind,     "filtered_training_data.txt")
writematrix(ftrainc,     "filtered_training_classes.txt")
writematrix(ftestd,      "filtered_test_data.txt")
writematrix(ftestc,      "filtered_test_classes.txt")

'''
The following function filters the data.
'''
function [filtered_run] = initial_filtering(run, trials)
%FILTERING This function filters the EEG signal from each electrode of one
%run.

frequency         = 512;
nyquist           = frequency / 2;
seconds_per_trial = 5;
pretrial_length   = 712;
posttrial_length  = 512;
epoch_length      = frequency * seconds_per_trial + posttrial_length + pretrial_length;
nr_of_trials      = 20;
baseline_period   = frequency;

cols                  = size(run, 2);
trial_starting_points = trials;
data                  = run;

% Create a highpass, lowpass and notch filter
[b_high, a_high]   = butter(6, 2 / nyquist, "high");
[b_low, a_low]     = butter(10, 60 / nyquist, "low");
[b_notch, a_notch] = iirnotch(50 / nyquist, 50 / nyquist / 10);

% Filter with highpass, lowpass and notch filter
for j = 1:cols
    electrode = data(:, j);
    filtered_electrode = filtfilt(b_high, a_high, electrode);
    filtered_electrode = filtfilt(b_low, a_low, filtered_electrode);
    filtered_electrode = filtfilt(b_notch, a_notch, filtered_electrode);
    data(:, j) = filtered_electrode;
end

% Using ICA to remove artifacts
[icasig, A, W] = fastica(data', ...
    'epsilon', 0.0005, ...
    'stabilization', 'on', ...
    'verbose', 'on');

% Nr of standard deviations away from mean as threshold
k = 3;

% Calculate kurtosis of independent components
kurtosis_values = kurtosis(icasig, 0, 2);
mean_kurtosis = mean(kurtosis_values);
std_kurtosis = std(kurtosis_values);
threshold_kurtosis = mean_kurtosis + (k * std_kurtosis);

% Calculate spectral power of independent components
spectral_power = sum(abs(fft(icasig).^2), 2);
mean_power = mean(spectral_power);
std_power = std(spectral_power);
threshold_power = mean_power + (k * std_power);

% Thresholding to identify artifact components
artifact_indices = find(kurtosis_values > threshold_kurtosis | spectral_power > threshold_power);

% Remove artifact components from icasig and A
clean_icasig = icasig;
clean_icasig(artifact_indices, :) = [];
clean_A = A;
clean_A(:, artifact_indices) = [];

% Reconstruct the cleaned EEG data
data = (clean_A * clean_icasig)';

% Segment into epochs and baseline normalize each epoch individually
filtered_run = zeros(nr_of_trials * cols, epoch_length);
for i = 1:nr_of_trials
    epoch_index = trial_starting_points(i) - pretrial_length;
    epoch       = data(epoch_index:(epoch_index+epoch_length-1), :);
    
    for j = 1:cols
        baseline     = epoch(1:baseline_period, j);
        baseline_avg = mean(baseline);
        baseline_std = std(baseline);
        epoch(:, j)  = (epoch(:, j) - baseline_avg) / baseline_std;  
    end
    
    idx = (i-1)*cols + 1;
    filtered_run(idx:(idx+cols-1), :) = epoch';
end
end

'''
This file next is the main script that loads the filtered data, performs CSP-filtering (separate function), feature extraction (separate function) and fits an ML-model.
'''
% Main script to fit ML-model
% Define constants
nr_of_subjects            = 14;
nr_of_training_runs       = 5;
nr_of_test_runs           = 3;
nr_of_trials              = 20;
nr_of_electrodes          = 15;
nr_of_subbands            = 2;
rows_per_run              = nr_of_trials * nr_of_electrodes * nr_of_subbands;
rows_per_training_session = nr_of_training_runs * rows_per_run;
rows_per_test_session     = nr_of_test_runs * rows_per_run;
seconds_per_trial         = 5;
frequency                 = 512;
data_points_per_trial     = frequency * seconds_per_trial;
nyquist                   = frequency / 2;
total_nr_of_training_rows = rows_per_training_session * nr_of_subjects;
total_nr_of_test_rows     = rows_per_test_session * nr_of_subjects;

% Load the data files
training_data    = readmatrix("filtered_training_data.txt");
training_classes = readmatrix("filtered_training_classes.txt");
test_data        = readmatrix("filtered_test_data.txt");
test_classes     = readmatrix("filtered_test_classes.txt");

% Pre-allocate structs and matrices for the data and features
StoreTrainData    = cell(total_train_trial, 1);
StoreTestData     = cell(total_test_trial, 1);
training_features = zeros(total_train_trial, N_features);
test_features     = zeros(total_test_trial, N_features);

% Convert the data into structs (each entry will be matrix of one trial)
total_train_trial = 1400;
total_test_trial  = 840;
for i = 1:total_train_trial
    index = (i-1)*nr_of_electrodes + 1;
    StoreTrainData{i} = training_data(index:(index+14), :);
end
for i = 1:total_test_trial
    index = (i-1)*nr_of_electrodes + 1;
    StoreTestData{i}  = test_data(index:(index+14), :);
end

training_classes = training_classes(1:15:end);
test_classes     = test_classes(1:15:end);


% Number of CSP filter components and nr. of features
numChannels       = 6;    
N_features        = 19 * numChannels;

% Calculate CSP filters
csp_filters = CSP(StoreTrainData, training_classes);

% Calculate the CSP-filtered data and the features
csp_filtered_training_data = cell(total_train_trial, 1);
csp_filtered_test_data     = cell(total_test_trial, 1);
for i = 1:total_train_trial
    csp_filtered_training_data{i} = csp_filters' * StoreTrainData{i};
    features = feature_extraction(csp_filtered_training_data{i});
    training_features(i, :) = reshape(features, 1, []);
end
for i = 1:total_test_trial
    csp_filtered_test_data{i} = csp_filters' * StoreTestData{i};
    features = feature_extraction(csp_filtered_test_data{i});
    test_features(i, :) = reshape(features, 1, []);
end

% Create array of feature names
feature_names = strings(1, N_features);
for i = 1:N_features
    feature_names(i) = "Feature" + num2str(i);
end 

% Combine features for each trial with the corresponding class
featureTrain = array2table([training_features, training_classes], "VariableNames", [feature_names, "Class"]);
featureTest  = array2table([test_features, test_classes],         "VariableNames", [feature_names, "Class"]);

% Specify options and fit model
options = struct("Optimizer","asha", ...
    "UseParallel", true, ...
    "MaxObjectiveEvaluations", 500);
Mdl     = fitcauto(training_features, training_classes, ...
    "Learners", "all", ...
    "HyperparameterOptimizationOptions", options);

confusionchart(test_classes, predict(Mdl, test_features))

'''
This function extracts the CSP-filters:
'''
function [csp_filters] = CSP(datacell, training_classes)
%CSP This function calculates the CSP filters for the data. The input is a
%cell array of matrices

% Get size of data
total_train_trial = size(datacell, 1);

% Pre-allocate covariance matrices for each class
cov_matrices_rh   = cell(0, 1);
cov_matrices_feet = cell(0, 1);

% Calculate the covariance matrix for each trial
for i = 1:total_train_trial
    if training_classes(i) == 1
        cov_matrices_rh{end+1}   = cov(datacell{i}');
    else 
        cov_matrices_feet{end+1} = cov(datacell{i}');
    end
end

% Estimate the mean covariance amtrix of each class
S1 = mean(cat(3, cov_matrices_rh{:}), 3);
S2 = mean(cat(3, cov_matrices_feet{:}), 3);

% Solve the eigenvalue decmoposition problem
[V1, D1] = eig(S1);
[W, ~]   = eig(S1 \ ((S1+S2) * D1));
[~, idx] = sort(diag(D1), 'descend');
W        = W(:, idx);

% Use the filters from the 3 smallest and 3 largest eigenvalues
csp_filters = W(:, [1:3, 13:15]);
end

'''
This last function extracts features:
'''
function [features] = feature_extraction(data)
%FEATURE_EXTRACTION Given some data, extracts different features of the
%data. "data" must be a matrix where each row is a trial signal.

% Define constants
frequency  = 512;
baseline_period   = frequency;
pretrial_length   = 712;
posttrial_length  = 512;
[N_channels, N_datapoints] = size(data);

% Create subband-intervals
theta_bands1 = [4, 5, 6];
theta_bands2 = [6, 7, 8];

alpha_bands1 = [7, 9, 11];
alpha_bands2 = [10, 12, 14];

beta_bands1   = [13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28];
beta_bands2   = [17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32];

lgamma_bands1 = [30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50, 54];
lgamma_bands2 = [36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60];

subbands = [[theta_bands1, alpha_bands1, beta_bands1, lgamma_bands1]', ...
    [theta_bands2, alpha_bands2, beta_bands2, lgamma_bands2]'];

N_subbands = size(subbands, 1);


% Calculate the baseline mean power for each frequency band
baseline            = mean(data(:, 1:baseline_period));
baseline_N          = length(baseline);
baseline_resolution = frequency / baseline_N;
baseline_freqs      = (0:baseline_N-1) * baseline_resolution;
baseline_fft        = fft(baseline);
baseline_power      = abs(baseline_fft).^2;
baseline_avg_power  = zeros(1, N_subbands);

for i = 1:N_subbands
    low  = subbands(i, 1);
    high = subbands(i, 2);

    band_indices          = baseline_freqs >= low & baseline_freqs <= high;
    avg_band_power        = mean(baseline_power(band_indices));
    baseline_avg_power(i) = avg_band_power;
end

features = zeros(N_channels, N_subbands);

% Loop over each trial, split the trial into the subbands and calculate
% features
trial_resolution = frequency / 2560;
trial_freqs = (0:2560-1) * trial_resolution;

for i = 1:N_channels
    trial       = data(i, (pretrial_length+1):(end-posttrial_length));
    trial_fft   = fft(trial);
    trial_power = abs(trial_fft).^2;
    
    % Calculate relative band power as features
    for j = 1:N_subbands
        low  = subbands(j, 1);
        high = subbands(j, 2);
        band_indices     = trial_freqs >= low & trial_freqs <= high;
        rel_trial_power  = 10 * log10(trial_power(band_indices) ./ baseline_avg_power(j));
        features(i, j)   = mean(rel_trial_power);
    end
end

% CSP Log Power

% Time-Domain Features

% Frequency-Domain Features

'''
I know the code could probably more efficient but thank you in advance for any help.
Edit: According to the paper i loosely follow the experiement was as follows: "The paradigm was based on the cue-guided GrazBCI training paradigm" and "Participants had the task of performing sustained (5 seconds) kinaesthetic motor imagery (MI) of the right hand and of the feet each as instructed by the cue. Feedback was presented in form of a white coloured bar-graph."

IMO this is way too much code and complexity to debug in one go. I suggest breaking it down into individual steps/blocks, testing and verifying each with well defined test signals and predicable answers, then putting it all together again with test signals, and than slowly increasing the complexity of the test signals and work your way up to real ECG signals. Don't try something complicated until you have fully verified that the simple stuff works.

@Hilmar Thank you for the response. I will definitely go through all the code again step by step. I just don't know the problem is a results of bugs in the code or that my pipeline is just not good enough, that is, I need better filtering and features.
